# Understanding a struct in c - a uart config

Tags: c, struct, uart

I'm looking at the config for a UART on an mcu. There is a structure describing the status of the UART below.

At the beginning of `main()` there is this line of code

`uart_status_t uart_status __attribute__((unused)) = 0;`

Could somebody explain what this line does?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to do a little search?

Comment: Used for avoiding compiler warnings. Use Google...

Comment: it is not a structure but an enumeration. The declaration sets uart_status to UART_IDLE. THe gcc documentation states : [unused]means that the variable is meant to be possibly unused. GCC will not produce a warning for this variable.

Comment: @clarasoft-it Many thanks

Comment: @clarasoft-it That could be an answer. Just add some references..

Comment: For the gcc compiler directive, please see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html

Comment: A better title would be "What is the meaning of `__attribute__((unused))`?"

Answer (score 0):

it is not a structure but an enumeration. The declaration sets uart_status to UART_IDLE. THe gcc documentation states : [unused]means that the variable is meant to be possibly unused. GCC will not produce a warning for this variable.

For the gcc compiler directive, please see [gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html)

– clarasoft-it